# Which license do I get for Windows Server 2008

Tags: licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I want to run a server with windows 2008. Which version license should I get? How many times can I install the license? Like if I reformat can I re-use the license? How many server can use the same license?

I'm seeing prices from 20$ to 2000$, which one is right for me?

I'm looking at prices from http://www.buycheapsoftware.com/ Has anyone have any experience with this company?

Answer (score 0):

Why buy from that website (a bit sketchy, no?) instead of buying directly from Microsoft?

As far as which channel (Windows Server packages) to purchase, check out [the graph on Microsoft's site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/2008-r2-buy.aspx).

I am fairly certain that you can format and re-use the license. However, you should contact Microsoft for details.

When you're ready to purchase, check out [Microsoft Store](http://www.microsoftstore.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would buy a windows 2008 server licenses from Microsoft or a Microsoft certified dealer. To be honest I do not see the question. Unless you are asking to buy an illegal license.

Your 3rd option would be to subscribe to Microsoft technet and get a Development/Single user license. This is $200 last time I checked and basically you get a license to every single MS product.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough.